# What is the difference between Postcss and grunt or gulp?

Tags: css, gruntjs, gulp

No doubt this question will be marked as not appropriate but thought I'd ask anyway :-). So yeah, what is the difference between Postcss and grunt or gulp? I've read a few articles and watched some videos but can't get my head around the difference. The articles mention adding vendor prefixes etc but I can't understand what Postcss offers that I can't get from grunt of gulp. Interested to hear your views.

Thanks David.

Comment: Seemingly the articles you read were not informative. Which ones did you read?

Comment: [tuts](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/postcss-deep-dive-what-you-need-to-know--cms-24535?utm_source=CSS-Weekly&utm_campaign=Issue-182&utm_medium=email)

Answer (score 1):

Search for

```
grunt vs gulp
```

Then you get answers like

http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/grunt-vs-gulp/

And then have a look at

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-postcss

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-postcss

Comment: Thanks for your response Hannes. I probably didn't make myself clear. I wasn't asking about gulp vs grunt but more about what Postcss brings to the table.

Answer (score 1):

Postcss processes a variety of custom plugins (written in .js) that provide linting, autoprefixer, sass styles, etc. to css files.

You could compare it to Sass or Less more than gulp or grunt.

Postcss can actually use gulp or grunt to execute.

There are over 200 plugins currently written to accomplish a wide variety of tasks, all focused on modifying css files in one way or another. You only run the ones you need.

You can see the full list here:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/blob/master/docs/plugins.md